# Can the PA1616D GPS module connect to a backend server to send GPS updates to a mobile phone?

Tags: gps, iot, lte

I am building an IOT device that will be moving around outdoors and will not be able to have a secure wifi connection. I want to be able to know the location of this device at all times on my mobile phone, so I am using a [PA1616D](https://www.cdtop-tech.com/products/pa1616d) to be able to get GPS data.

I am able to access this GPS data, but i'm confused how I then get this data onto a backend server that I can then access with my mobile phone to get the GPS updates? Is this unit strictly a GPS module and it cannot access a server? Do I need to add another module such as the [GM02S](https://www.sequans.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/PI-GM02S-1-20200910_WEB.pdf) to then take this GPS data and send it through LTE to a backend server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that device is just the GPS receiever, and it sends its data over serial (UART or I2C).  You'll need something else to get a data connection, such as the device you listed.  Most small systems use a much simpler one, such as the SIM800L or similar, and a microcontroller to coordinate. (Here's [tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/Homemade-Realtime-GPS-Tracker-SIM800L-Ublox-NEO-6M/) with an Arduino and very similar goals.)

[image]
From [Linked page](https://www.cdtop-tech.com/products/pa1616d)